# XSLT - testing each node for conditions, and breaking the test if the condition is met

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I would like 1 output returned for two types cases. The first case must loop thru nodes to determine if it's met. Here is the XML:

```
<in:inputs 
  xmlns:in="http://www.composite.net/ns/transformation/input/1.0">
   <in:result name="GetCart">
      <root xmlns="">
        <USC_Purchase ProductPrice="95.0000" 
                      PriceRuleID="1810" 
                      PurchaseQuantity="-1.00" 
                      PaymentNotRequiredQuantity="0.00" 
                      PaymentRequiredQuantity="-1.00" 
                      PaymentRequiredTotal="-95.000000" 
                      PurchaseStatus="R" 
                      RefundTotalAllowed="0.00">
          <USC_Product_PriceRule 
            PriceRuleID="1810" 
            PriceRuleName="Full Attendee" 
            PriceRulePriority="1" 
            PriceRuleStatus="A" 
            WebUserGroups="13CONF-M001" 
            ExcludeWebUserGroups="" 
            ProductPrice="95.0000" 
            ExternalCode="" 
            PercentOfProductCode="" 
            OptionID="0" 
            FriendlyName="Discounted Rate" 
            StartEndRestrictionID="0" 
            ClassID="0" 
            IsHidden="0"/>
        </USC_Purchase>
        <USC_Purchase ProductPrice="55.0000" 
                      PurchaseQuantity="-4.00" 
                      PaymentNotRequiredQuantity="0.00" 
                      PaymentRequiredQuantity="-4.00" 
                      PaymentRequiredTotal="-220.000000" 
                      PurchaseStatus="R" 
                      RefundTotalAllowed="568.00">
          <USC_Product_PriceRule/>
        </USC_Purchase>
```

Here is my unfinished XSLT, which starts at the first USC_Purchase node:

```
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="@PurchaseStatus='R' 
        and ($purchase_total*($purchase_total >=0)
           - $purchase_total*($purchase_total &lt; 0)) 
           > @RefundTotalAllowed">
       We are having issues processing your refund online. 
       Please contact us for assistance.
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <!-- insert credit card form here -->
      </xsl:otherwise>
```

This works great...only if the first product met those conditions. The other products go unchecked. A for-each loop at the top of the xsl:choose statement would return multiple messages, and also the credit card form if any of the products were passed fine. (grr!)

My question is - is it possible to loop multiple purchase nodes and stop once a single case is met?

Here are the steps (in case my explanation is throwing anyone off):

1. Choose between two outputs (error message and credit card form).
2. For each USC_Purchase node, if 'X' condition(s) are met on any node, display the single error message.
3. Otherwise, display credit card form.

If more information is needed please let me know.

*edit*

sure, purchase_total is determined by the sum of all paymentrequiredtotals, so:

```
<xsl:variable 
  name="purchase_total" 
  select="sum(USC_Purchase/@PaymentRequiredTotal)" />
```

Comment: Any chance we could see a biiiit more of your XSLT?  Particularly, how is `$purchase_total` being determined?

Comment: Thanks for adding the logic for `purchase_total`.  So I'm having some trouble understanding the logic of when an error mesage should be displayed. It looks like `purchase_total` is determined as the sum across all rows. Should this be compared against the sum of the `@RefundTotalAllowed` values, or compared individually against each `@RefundTotalAllowed`? It also looks like you're doing an absolute value calculation there, so if the absolute value of the sums of `@PaymentRequiredTotal` is > `RefundTotalAllowed`, show the error? I'm having trouble making sense of the logic here.

Comment: That's correct. If the absolute value of PaymentRequiredTotal is > RefundTotalAllowed, the error should be shown. Basically RefundTotalAllowed determines if the user paid by creditcard for that particular product, and if they did, return the maximum amount that we can allow back to that credit card. if they paid by check, RefundTotalAllowed will be 0. I hope that helps clarify things. @JLRishe

Comment: Ok, so you just want to compare, on a row-by-row basis, @PaymentRequiredTotal against @RefundTotalAllowed?  Your definition of `purchase_total` appears to be summing the @PaymentRequiredTotal values of all rows, but is that unintentional?

Comment: Sorry I told you wrong! if the absolute value of purchase_total > RefundTotalAllowed, the error is shown. RefundTotalAllowed, while making sure the product was paid by credit card previously, is also returning the maximum purchase amount any credit card. There will only be one refund, so RefundTotalAllowed has to be greater than the purchase_total for each product. It seems inefficient to have this comparison done each time (since all products with a valid refund will have the same refundtotalallowed and purchasetotal, but i couldn't think of another way to process this on a per product basis.

Comment: Ok, to just make sure we're totally clear, `purchase_total` is the sum of the `@PaymentRequiredTotal`s _across all rows_. If the absolute value of that sum is greater than the `@RefundTotalAllowed` _any row_ that has `@PurchaseStatus = 'R'`, show the error.  Did I get that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I think I finally understand your requirements. Due to its functional nature, XSLTs do not tend to employ "loop until" logic (it can be done, but is generally not employed when another approach is available). Instead, tests are generally applied across all possible targets at once to see if a condition is met for any of them.  I believe the following should do what you are looking to do:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:variable
      name="purchase_total"
      select="sum(USC_Purchase/@PaymentRequiredTotal)" />
    <xsl:variable
      name="purchase_total_abs"
      select="$purchase_total * (1 - 2 * ($purchase_total &lt; 0))" />

    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="USC_Purchase[@PurchaseStatus  ='R' and
                                   $purchase_total_abs > @RefundTotalAllowed]">
        We are having issues processing your refund online. Please contact us for assistance.
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:call-template name="CreditCardForm" />
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="CreditCardForm">
    <!-- Credit form-->
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

To keep the formulas short, first `purchase_total`, then its absolute value are determined, and then a test is done to see if any of the `USC_Purchase`s match the error condition. If so, the error message is shown, and if not, the credit card form is shown.

Comment: I think this will work for the first USC_Purchase node, but not for any additional ones? The RefundTotalAllowed attribute attached to each USC_Purchase node is based of its particular product. So for example, if we had 2 USC_purchase records, and the first USC_Purchase node failed the test, it would pull the creditcard form. However, if the second USC_Purchase record could not be refunded, there wouldn't be a check. A for-each loop before the choose would return both for each usc_purchase record.  I do appreciate your help, but I don't think what I'm trying to accomplish is possible in XSLT.

Comment: @user673869 My XSLT above should apply the test to all USC_Purchase nodes simultaneously, display the error text (and only the error text) if it matches any of them, and show the credit card form if not. Have you tried using it, or are you declaring it unsuitable before even executing that courtesy?

Comment: My apologies @JLRishe - this is exactly what I'm looking for! If you can't tell I'm bad at explaining xslt and assumed I butchered my explaination of what I'm trying to accomplish. But, after a second take at your code I noticed the brackets (that grabs the first USC_Purchase that meets the conditions). You're awesome, I owe you a big sorry. Thank you very much! Consider this solved.

Comment: @user673869 Always glad to help. :) In future, please be careful to clearly and thoroughly define the whole problem and all of the details involved. As the above example demonstrates, though it may seem that the gritty details are irrelevant to the answer you believe you are seeking (in this case, find a way to stop a loop midway through), often the most appropriate answer is dependant on these smaller details, and could be something you never expected. I hope to have the opportunity to help you make sense of XSLT again in the future. :)

Answer (score 0):

**This slightly shorter transformation processes each `USC_Purchase` element as required -- and this is clearly shown in the results**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:variable name="vTotalPaymentRequired"
   select="sum(/*/*/root/USC_Purchase/@PaymentRequiredTotal)"/>

 <xsl:template match="USC_Purchase">
  Purchase <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
   <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test=
     "@PurchaseStatus  ='R'
    and not(@RefundTotalAllowed + $vTotalPaymentRequired >= 0)">
         <xsl:text>
          We are having issues processing your refund online.
         </xsl:text>
         <xsl:text> Please contact us for assistance.</xsl:text>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
     Credit Form displayed here
    </xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="USC_Product_PriceRule"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<in:inputs
  xmlns:in="http://www.composite.net/ns/transformation/input/1.0">
   <in:result name="GetCart">
      <root xmlns="">
        <USC_Purchase ProductPrice="95.0000"
                      PriceRuleID="1810"
                      PurchaseQuantity="-1.00"
                      PaymentNotRequiredQuantity="0.00"
                      PaymentRequiredQuantity="-1.00"
                      PaymentRequiredTotal="-95.000000"
                      PurchaseStatus="R"
                      RefundTotalAllowed="0.00">
          <USC_Product_PriceRule
            PriceRuleID="1810"
            PriceRuleName="Full Attendee"
            PriceRulePriority="1"
            PriceRuleStatus="A"
            WebUserGroups="13CONF-M001"
            ExcludeWebUserGroups=""
            ProductPrice="95.0000"
            ExternalCode=""
            PercentOfProductCode=""
            OptionID="0"
            FriendlyName="Discounted Rate"
            StartEndRestrictionID="0"
            ClassID="0"
            IsHidden="0"/>
        </USC_Purchase>
        <USC_Purchase ProductPrice="55.0000"
                      PurchaseQuantity="-4.00"
                      PaymentNotRequiredQuantity="0.00"
                      PaymentRequiredQuantity="-4.00"
                      PaymentRequiredTotal="-220.000000"
                      PurchaseStatus="R"
                      RefundTotalAllowed="568.00">
          <USC_Product_PriceRule/>
        </USC_Purchase>
    </root>
  </in:result>
</in:inputs>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
  Purchase 1
          We are having issues processing your refund online.
          Please contact us for assistance.
  Purchase 2
     Credit Form displayed here
```